# mutual visibility of nodes on a grid

Tags: python-3.x, graph, grid

I have a simple grid, and I need check two nodes for mutual visibility. All walls and nodes coordinations is known. I need check two nodes for mutual visibility.

I have tried use vectors, but I didn't get acceptable result. This algorithm works, but it bad fit in my program, because of this i must do transformations of data to get acceptable result.

I used this code for check nodes for mutual visibility:

```py
def finding_vector_grid(start, goal):
    distance = [start[0]-goal[0], start[1]-goal[1]]
    norm = math.sqrt(distance[0] ** 2 + distance[1] ** 2)
    if norm == 0: return [1, 1]
    direction = [(distance[0]/norm), (distance[1]/norm)]
    return direction

def finding_vector_path(start, goal):
    path = [start]
    direction = finding_vector_grid((start[0]*cell_width, start[1]*cell_height),
        (goal[0]*cell_width, goal[1]*cell_height))
    x, y = start[0]*cell_width, start[1]*cell_height
    point = start

    while True:
        if point not in path and in_map(point):
            path.append(point)
        elif not in_map(point):
            break

        x -= direction[0]
        y -= direction[1]
        point = (x//cell_width, y//cell_height)
    return path

def vector_obstacles_clean(path, obstacles):
    result = []
    for node in path:
        if node in obstacles:
            result.append(node)
            break
        result.append(node)
    return result
```

for example:

```py
path =  finding_vector_path((0, 0), (0, 5))
path = vector_obstacles_clean(path, [(0, 3)])
```

1. in_map - check if point not abroad map frontiers;
2. start, goal - tuples width x and y coords;
3. cell_width, cell_height - int variables with node width and height in pixels (I use pygame for visualization graph).

I have not any problems with this method, but it works not with graphs, it works "by itself", it not quite the that I need to. I am not good at English, please forgive me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted seems perfectly nice,
and your question doesn't clarify what needs improving.

Rather than doing FP arithmetic on vectors,
you might prefer to increment an integer X or Y pointer
one pixel at a time.
Consider using [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm),
which enumerates pixels in the line of sight
between `start` and `goal`.
The key observation is that for a given slope
it notices whether X or Y will increment faster,
and loops on that index.

Comment: Thanks, you don't understand my question, but answer it. This algorithm works directly by nodes coords, without transforms. Exactly that I need. I didn't hear about this method.